# Countersunk screw integration

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am using CAD to add a hole for an M5 countersunk screw.

The countersunk angle is 90 degrees.

I am concerned about clearances and getting the shape of the countersunk hole correct. I am worried that a mismatch of angles might result in self-loosening, and about the transition from the countersunk head to the shaft of the screw (which is a small fillet).

To make the countersunk hole, I created a cone matching the dimensions of the screw head, subtracted it from the target; I then added clearance by increasing the diameter of the cone by 0.2mm.

Does this sound like the correct approach?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not a counterbore?

Comment: I just googled what a counterbore is. I could have used that approach, but that would have added frontal area to the part where I was trying to reduce it.

Comment: Unsure what you mean by a counterbore adding frontal area.

Comment: I'm at the limit of my knowledge on this. I wanted to reduce part frontal area; a countersunk screw achieves this. A counterbore would require removal of more material closer to the shank (because the head of an ordinary socket-head screw is of consistent cross section), meaning the in-practice implementation would need to be thicker in order to maintain overall strength. I welcome correction.

Comment: You could perhaps use a thin head socket cap head screw if you can get ahold of them.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.

Comment: There's also more than one degree of "low-profileness" in socket cap head screws.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: whats the manufacturing method and material?

Comment: Nylon 12. Powder bed additive manufacturing.